# How to do make mysite.com/post-name/sub-post?

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have a small doubt and wonder if I could help.

By adding a post, I have the permalink "http://www.mysite.com/post-name". I would like to know how to post a parent, for example, "http://www.mysql.com/post-name/video". I wanted to add sub posts in the posts, but do not know how.

To add pages, simply add the new page as a parent of another page, but does not have this option for posts.

I was looking for something like WP Rewrite class or any other way to do this.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you can't achieve your goal with pages? Posts are not intended to have parents, children or siblings. Why'd they?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom post type and set hierarchical to true, but keep the post capability role.  The link below is a good starting place.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Although I would strongly recommend using some sort of javascript html css workaround.  Maybe a jquery ui tabbed interface located inside of your single.php theme like "http://www.mysite.com/post-name/#video"